# How do I simulate a click on a specific position using phpUnit / selenium?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I am using phpunit 3.7 and selenium for testing. In order to test a text highlighting functionality, I want to click on a specific x,y position within a div (contains the text).

I tried the moveTo() function ([see](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCaseTest.php)) but I always get an error, although the element is an instance of the PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element class: "PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Exception: Only moving over an element is supported. Please pass a PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element instance.".

```
$div = $this->byCssSelector('#texthighlight-instant_feedback div div');

if ($div instanceof PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element) {
     $this->moveto(array(
        'element' => $div,
        'xoffset' => 100,
        'yofsset' => 5
     ));
     $this->click();
} else {
    throw new PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Exception('no instanceof PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_Element');
}
```

In addition the 'click' command seems to be not existent or not supported.
I just started using phpunit / selenium and hope someone else may now how to simulate a click on a specific position within a element? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you check sourcecode in SessionCommand\MoveTo.php, it seems that you shouldn't do

```
$this->moveto(array(
    'element' => $div,
    'xoffset' => 100,
    'yofsset' => 5
 ));
```

But instead:

```
$this->moveto($div);
```

However, I'm getting and BadMethodCallException: The command 'moveTo' is not existent or not supported yet no matter which way of calling it I tried.

Reason I want to move the cursor: so i can right-click an element...

**Edit:**

Looking through the code it dawned on me i'm calling moveTo, not moveto.... At least I got rid of my exception. BTW: my suggestion should still work with your problem.

What problem are you having with click()? There are two different click()-methods, one on the session ($this->click()) and one on the element ($div->click).

**Edit2:**

click() doesnt seem to be initialized as an available command on session. Buttondown and buttonup are defined. Using first buttondown and then buttonup should give you your click.

I'm still out of luck though. buttondown and buttonup dont seem to pass an associative array as JSON params to the Selenium server, so I cant simulate middle or right mouse button.

For now I added click as genericpost option in Session.php, because then I can call:

```
$this->click('button'=>2);
```

to rightclick the element I just moved the cursor over.